# Changes to developer program: will email-address still be available to all developers?

Tags: linkedin-api

I went through the description on changes and one thing is not clear to me:

Our app reads the email-address field for authenticated user (via `/v1/people/~:(email-address)`).  That field is listed as a separate group, "Email Fields", in the [profile fields doc](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields), but it does not appear anywhere in [Data Fields documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields).

How or where can I check if that field is going to be available to all developers after May 12th?

Comment: So would I if this wasn't where LinkedIn sends people for developer support :)

Comment: It doesn't matter where LinkedIn (or any other outside source) sends you. Questions here still have to meet the SO guidelines. This has been discussed repeatedly at [meta] and [meta.se] in the past.

Comment: It doesn't matter where LinkedIn (or any other outside source) sends you for support. We used to frequently get Facebook user accuont questions, too, because they had an SO link in their developer's pages and non-developers would see and use it. Questions here still have to meet the SO guidelines. This has been discussed repeatedly at [meta] and [meta.se] in the past. Reconsidered, though, after re-reading your question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is and will remain possible to request member email addresses using LinkedIn's API.  There was an oversight in the documentation that has since been corrected.

The following API request will return the member's email address provided the OAuth 2.0 connection asks for the **r_emailaddress** member permission:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address)
```